# What can cause chrome to display a web page all smudged and how to troubleshoot? (image included)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, webpack, web-frontend

What could cause Chrome on mobile to display a web page appears to smudge elements when scrolling the page, such as the below image.

The page uses many icons from Fontawesome and uses Google fonts (font source NPM package), reactjs, jQuery and is packaged using webpack. It includes multiple webpack bundles on the same page.

What could be the approach to troubleshoot this issue?

[image: smudged text]
The example below is at URL https://uquiz.com/DlVmXD:

The issue appears to have surfaced with the inclusion of the additional react component further down the page that shows suggestions of other content. Apparently it doesn't happen when the suggestions aren't displayed such as on this embed URL of the same content: https://uquiz.com/quiz/embed/DlVmXD/what-romance-trope-are-you?embed=true

I have tried it on many devices and it is fine and thousands of people are successfully able to use the page without issue every single day, but many people are reporting this issue. Every person that I have investigated is using Chrome on a mobile device.

I can't find anything to do with this behviour on the githubs for the main libraries that I use so I'm left thinking it could be a hardware issue. Could it be?

Comment: Similar to Layout Thrashing. You may be assigning style.width or style.height somewhere in the loop. You need to look at the code. Similar issue
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66450070/are-layout-thrashing-reflow-the-same-meaning-in-html#:~:text=Layout%20thrashing%20occurs%20when%20we,cause%20a%20cascade%20of%20changes.